# Can you save base64 data as a file with ngCordova?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

In this [tutorial](http://devdactic.com/how-to-capture-and-store-images-with-ionic/), the author uses the `FileURI` to copy the image from the temporary location to the device location, and finally returning the `nativeURL` of this copied file.

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileURI, success, fail);
```

Instead of the `FileURI` I have a **base64** **string** (imageData) which I want to save also on the device location and return the `nativeURL` of this saved image.

Is this possible and how would one achieve this with ngCordova?

**1. draw on canvas in controller**

```
$scope.drawAndSave = function() {

    $scope.targetImages = [{nativeURL: "img/newyork.jpg"}, {nativeURL: "img/newyork.jpg"}]

    drawCanvas().then(function(data){
      $scope.outputImages = data; // works fine, can save it

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
        FileFactory.saveCanvasToDataUrl(data[i])
      }

    });

    function drawCanvas() {
      var pResults = $scope.targetImages.map(function (imageObj) {
        return drawToCanvas(imageObj.nativeURL);
      });
      return $q.all(pResults);
    }

    function drawToCanvas(nativeURL) {
      return $q(function (resolve) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = nativeURL;

        img.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            resolve(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"));
        };

      });
    } // draw to canvas

  }
```

**2. save canvas as image with for the input `fileURI` the `canvas.toDataUrl()` `dataURI`.**

```
.factory('FileFactory', function($cordovaFile, $q) {

    var saveCanvasToDataUrl = function(imageData) {
        copyFileURI(imageData) 
    }

    // // http://devdactic.com/how-to-capture-and-store-images-with-ionic/
    // todo: get file uri and copy it
    var copyFileURI = function(fileURI) {

        window.alert("saving ")

        var q = $q.defer();
        onImageSuccess(fileURI);
        function onImageSuccess(fileURI) {
            createFileEntry(fileURI);
        }
        function createFileEntry(fileURI) {
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileURI, copyFile, fail);
        }
        function copyFile(fileEntry) {
            var name = fileEntry.fullPath.substr(fileEntry.fullPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            var newName = makeid() + name;
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function(fileSystem2) {
                fileEntry.copyTo(
                    fileSystem2,
                    newName,
                    onCopySuccess,
                    fail
            );
            },
            fail);
        }
        function onCopySuccess(entry) {
            q.resolve(entry.nativeURL) 
        }
        function fail(error) {
            q.reject(error)
            window.alert("fail: " + JSON.stringify(error))
        }
        function makeid() {
            var text = "";
            var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
            for (var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
            }
            return text;
        }

        return q.promise;
    } // copy file uri, return new native url


    var removeFile = function(nativeURL) {

        var name = nativeURL.substr(nativeURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        window.alert("trying to delete nativeURL name: " + nativeURL)
        window.alert("cordova file directory: " + cordova.file.dataDirectory)
        window.alert('name: ' + name)

        $cordovaFile.checkFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, name)
        .then(function (success) {

            window.alert("file found " + success)

            $cordovaFile.removeFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, name)
                .then(function (success) {
                    // success
                    window.alert("file deleted " + success)
                }, function (error) {
                // error
                window.alert("file not deleted error " + error)
                });

        }, function (error) {
        // error
            window.alert("file not ound " + JSON.stringify(error))
        });

    }

    return {
        copyFileURI: copyFileURI, 
        removeFile: removeFile,
        saveCanvasToDataUrl: saveCanvasToDataUrl
    }

});
```

Comment: You could probably just prepend `data:image/jpeg;base64,` (or replace jpeg with png) to the string and it'll function as a [data uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Comment: I tried that, by converting my canvas using .toDataUrl() and using that as an input but it gives me an encoding error (5)... Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, what does prepend mean and which process is encoding?

Comment: If you're using `.toDataURL()` then it's already in a URI and you don't need to change it. For example this is a URI... `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAoCAYAAACfKfiZAAAA9ElEQVRYhdXUuw0CMQwGYBdwgooKCViBlgnYivoqFqBjKwZBFIgCCA0FsvLyHycmllygc+zPOR1EZeG+aRKOpeQMHKufBlIAAo42WVoDZuz3VHD2pgHwZe5ZOFCAr84R0dwKAN+GOeDEDh8BwLUEwJvxPAvrn9oA30Zq198lYG0NQL8aEeDdGnARNI7VbEPSfQYiBeC3Et0euZ5U85zMatgMIEVoADYogv+Xo/kKLOctXihvH33Fj0RxdUBoyGANcIlnqoBBeZAYoL1pn4AWiP8H1Eb0AaiJMAXsJIAaCHHcFYePCICUhk/Q4aUItcgdeMhp9gGi4szUfEMdFgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`

Comment: Yes, so I tried to use that as a input for the fileURI but it returned me an encoding error... I will update my post soon with the code

Comment: I use this tutorial (http://devdactic.com/how-to-capture-and-store-images-with-ionic/) to save the data. When inputting the dataURI in the exact code, it gives me an encoding error :(

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried

Comment: Just included the code. Thank you for the look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code to save base64 string to file

```
// I assume your base64 string is stored in a variable 'imageData'
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("image.jpg", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}
function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}
function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    console.log("Start creating image file");
    writer.seek(0);
    writer.write(imageData);
    console.log("End creating image file. File created");
}
```

Grouping all the above into a function

```
function savefile(dataurl){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
    function (fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("image.jpg", {create: true, exclusive: false}, 
            function (fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.createWriter(function (writer) {
                    console.log("Start creating image file");
                    writer.seek(0);
                    writer.write(dataurl);
                    console.log("End creating image file. File created");
                }, fail);
            }, fail);
    }, fail);
}

function fail(){
    console.log("Error");
}
```

Now you can call the function by `savefile(dataurl)` where `dataurl` is the base64 string

**Updated:**

Above version didn't had the folder selection. In below function **app_folder_name** variable has to be replace to folder in device.

```
function savefile(dataurl){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
    function (fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory( app_folder_name, {create:true, exclusive: false},
        function(directory) {
            directory.root.getFile("image.jpg", {create: true, exclusive: false}, 
            function (fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.createWriter(function (writer) {
                    console.log("Start creating image file");
                    writer.seek(0);
                    writer.write(dataurl);
                    console.log("End creating image file. File created");
                }, fail);
            }, fail);
        }, fail);
    }, fail);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, could you explain where I input my base64 string.

Comment: Hi Lepanto. Thanks for that. Could you explain what the fileSystem.root.getFile("image.jpg"...) does? I am trying to use imageData as an input from a canvas, not from an image.

Comment: It is the resultant / final / destination filename for the image that will be store in device and doesn't mean anything with the imagedata

Comment: Thank you. But where exactly is it being stored. I would like to know the path?

Comment: Like my console says it created and stored the file, but I dont see it in my library (iphone) and also dont know where it went.

Comment: John, I have updated the code. Previous version didn't have the getDirectory function which selects the folder in device

Comment: What exactly does imageData contain? Is it a data url in form of 
"data:image/png;base64, <imageData>...." or is it just the image string?